# handlebar not populating template correctly for JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

Hi I am making http get call to mvc controller action which returns JSON as below:

```
[
    {
        "PlanCode": "P001 ",
        "PlanName": "Plan1 "
    },
    {
        "PlanCode": "P002$ ",
        "PlanName": "Plan2$ "
    },
    {
        "PlanCode": "P003$ ",
        "PlanName": "Plan3$ "
    },
    {
        "PlanCode": "P004$ ",
        "PlanName": "Plan4$ "
    },
    {
        "PlanCode": "P005$ ",
        "PlanName": "Plan5$ "
    },
    {
        "PlanCode": "P006$ ",
        "PlanName": "Plan6$ "
    },
    {
        "PlanCode": "P007$ ",
        "PlanName": "Plan7$ "
    },
    {
        "PlanCode": "P007$ ",
        "PlanName": "Plan7$ "
    },
    {
        "PlanCode": "P008$ ",
        "PlanName": "Plan8$ "
    },
    {
        "PlanCode": "P009$ ",
        "PlanName": "Plan9$ "
    }
]
```

Using handlbar code as below:

```
var PLAN_METHOD = {

    handlerData: function (planJSON) {

        var templateSource = $("#plan-template").html();

        template = Handlebars.compile(templateSource);

           var context = planJSON;
            plansHTML = template({planJSON:context});


        $('#plans-div').html(plansHTML);

    },
    loadPlansData: function () {

        $.get("http://localhost:41801/plan/getplans",null,this.handlerData)

    }
};

$(document).ready(function () { 

    PLAN_METHOD.loadPlansData();
});
```

template html is as below:

```
<div id="plans-div" >
</div>

<script id="plan-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Plan Code</th>
                <th>Plan Name</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each Plans}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{this.PlanCode}}</td>
                <td>{{this.PlanName}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

Somehow 'plansHTML' in handlebar javascript code is not getting populated with JSON date rows. Please help

Comment: where is `plans-div` in your html? that should be an id.

Comment: sorry somehow didn't add above plans-div html. It's there as follows: <div id="plans-div" >
    </div> but still Somehow 'plansHTML' in handlebar javascript code is not getting populated with JSON data rows.

Comment: can you update your question to include `plans-div`

Comment: Updated to include plans-div

Answer (score 0):

Your template is looking for an array at the property `Plans` of the data. But your data does not have a `Plans` property. The solution is simply to use the correct property name in your template data object:

```
plansHTML = template({ Plans: context });
```